# Did orphan ever refer to the losing of a father?

Tags: meaning

It seems that a lot of the ideas of an "orphan" in ancient times only referred to the loss of father, rather than the loss of both parents.

In Chinese too it seems that the idea of an orphan (孤) originally only meant the bereavement of a dad.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orphan) does hint at its origin (emphasis my own):

> from Ancient Greek ὀρφανός (orphanós, “without parents, **fatherless**”)

but I'm not seeing whether or not this meaning evolved into English.

Did the idea of an orphan in English only ever refer to the loss of both parents?

Comment: Hello, 330. What do your researches into the etymology of the word turn up? Is there anything faintly or strongly suggestive of an answer? // Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. All questions should be accompanied by reasonable research, whether the findings are helpful or not, if only to avoid others duplicating effort fruitlessly.

Comment: [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/132728?rskey=L0vHNj&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) _1. A person, esp. a child, both of whose parents are dead (or, rarely, one of whose parents has died)_. And _Bereaved of parents; fatherless or motherless, or both._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've edited it to include research.

Comment: The word "orphan" as mentioned in Nigel J's comment is sometimes used to refer to someone who has only lost one parent. But I hadn't heard before of any particular association with losing a father vs. a mother.

Comment: [The Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/orphan) seems to claim that the 'fatherless' sense may not have made it from Greek to Latin: << c. 1300, from Late Latin orphanus "parentless child" ...  from Greek orphanos "orphaned, without parents, fatherless"  >>.  But I'd not consider this reference as being as authoritative as the lack of mention of the 'fatherless' sense by OED.

Comment: Your question is confusing: the title asks whether orphan ever referred to 'the losing of a father', while in the body of the question you ask about 'only ever refer to the loss of both parents'...

Answer (score 1):

The translation of ορφανους, *orphanous* in James 1:27 was rendered 'fatherless and motherless' in The Wycliffe translation of 1382. However The Wycliffe was taken from Jerome's Latin Vulgate, not the Greek original, so the Latin word may be more apposite in this case.

> to visite **fadirles and modirles** children, and widewis in her tribulacioun, and to kepe hym silf vndefoulid fro this world.

However the translations from the Greek - the 1534 Tyndale, 1535 Coverdale, 1537 Matthew's, 1539 Great, 1560 Geneva, 1568 Bishop's and in both the 1611 and 1769 King James' translations  - the Greek word ορφανους, orphanous *was given as 'fatherless' only.*

> to visit the **fatherlesse** and widowes in their affliction, and to keepe himselfe vnspotted from the world. [KJV 1611]

All references from [Textus Receptus Interlinear](http://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear/59001027)

Comment: The OED definition that you posted in the comments is relevant, but this doesn't seem to be since neither of these Bible quotes include the English word "orphan".

Comment: The OP is enquiring about the Greek original and its transition into English. I have catalogued its transition as 'fatherless' which is, to my mind, very relevant and, to my mind, what the OP was interested in.

Comment: The only reason Greek was mentioned in the question was because OP needed to show research and that's the etymology. It wasn't in the first revision of the question at all.

Comment: It's an interesting question. I was hoping there would be other contributions.

Comment: Taking it back further, to ancient Greek proper, the Lexicon of Lydell and Scott shows a very wide range of meaning for ‘orphanos’ (ορφανός):  not just parentless but deprived of almost anything:  L&S cites “bereft of a father; of children (Hekuba in Euripides’ tragedy); knowledge (Plato); living (ie poor); fish without sauce!  So why not mothers?  It must be women’s inferior status.  In most societies children have legally ‘belonged’ to the male parent till shockingly recent times. Athens had an ορφανοφυλαξ (orphanophylax) or guardian for children of fathers killed in war.